# Captcha not loading

Tags: captcha

New to the Exchange.
I have been using TOR for a couple of years now but recently I have been unable to see the Captcha on different sites. One site I can see it but it is giving me an incorrect Captcha message.
I know that it is probably something really simple but I have spent days on it and just cannot find out what the problem is. I use a Mac.

All the best to everyone,
Maf71

Comment: It sounds like the captcha is broken or they've simply blacklisted Tor. There was a case in the past where captchas failed because Google's servers refused to serve the content to some Tor exits that were on some extra-naughty list.

Comment: It's fixed. I tried deleting and reloading TOR, cleaning out caches etc. In the end there was a 'refresh TOR button'. One click. I knew it would be!